# Need Ansible to create new Ec2 instance Everytime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I Have an Ansible script That runs a Cloudformation script. The problem is The ansible script should run over and over a specified time to create an unlimited amount of servers on AWS just like running a Cloudformation createstack on AWS, but when ran more than once it keeps updating the same resource created. It just changes the Name. I have been tring to fix this for 2 days. I need a way to create a NEW server in aws no matter how many times I run the ansible script.  I believe the issue is the instance id. Since it sees one is created it doesn't attempt to create a new one. Here is my Cloudformation code uploaded to s3.

```
Parameters:
  KeyPair:
    Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
    Description: Connects to this
Resources:
  ec2:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
  ImageId: ami-04681a1dbd79675a5
  InstanceType: t2.micro
  KeyName: !Ref KeyPair
```

And This is my Ansible code to run the ec2 server in s3 bucket. Ran like ansible-playbook provision.yml

please help.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: first Task Provision ec2
      cloudformation:
        stack_name: 'provisiong-ec2'
        state: present
        region: us-east-1
        disable_rollback: true
        template_url: https://s3.amazonaws.com/randombuckets/ansy2-cloudformation.template
        template_parameters:
          KeyPair: rabbit
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not creating a new instance because the `stack_name` has not changed and your CFT only builds one host (which is already built).

Your immediate options are:

1. Create your instances using `AutoScalingGroups` (ASG) within `CloudFormation`.  You can pass in the minimum number of hosts (`MinSize`) as a parameter and ASG will take care of the rest.  You'll need to build in some logic to increment the count by one each iteration.
2. (not advised) Change the stack name every time you run the Ansible playbook
3. (not advised) Add another host to your CFT every time you want to run Ansible